# How to get the value of Loaction present in Response Header in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Restful webserivce(Jersey),I need to get the value of Location present in the Response Header

```
$http({
        method : "POST",
        url : ' http://localhost:8084/leasing-management/customers/',
        headers : {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json'
        },
        data :  $scope.customer
    })
    .success(function(dataFromServlet,status, headers) {
        console.log(status);
        if(status==201){
             alert( headers('Location') );
            console.log(headers('Content-Type'));
            showToasterBox("success","Customer Created Successfully ","Success");
            /*$location.path("customers/headers('Location')");*/
        }
        else{
            showToasterBox("error","Status : " + status + " - Application Error","Try Again");
        }
    })
    .error(function(dataFromServlet,status, headers) {
        showToasterBox("error","Status : " + status + " - Application Error","Try Again");
    });
```

If I  put alert for Loaction it says null.

Response Header:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:custom-header
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 20 Aug 2015 07:28:04 GMT
Location:http://localhost:8084/leasing-management/customers/10081
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Comment: you can console.log(headers()) to see if it really include the Location, BTW, is the Location same as the URL on you browser?

Comment: Hi Huan, the location is same as the URL i hit on browser, when i print my header has only the "content-type", it could able to find location

Comment: If it is the same as the URL on browser, why you don't just call $location service to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $location servcie?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Or you can use window.localtion?